# BizTalk 2010 and ESB 2.1

Tags: biztalk, esb-toolkit-2.1

I am new to ESB 2.1, I am migrating on ESB 1.1 project to ESB 2.1 and BizTalk 2010. I have developed on application which use itinerary file and push data to SQL server. I don't have itinerary project I have itinerary xml file (itinerary exported in xml format.)

Now when my received port get any records it create xml file in C:\Projects\Microsoft.Practices.ESB\Source\Samples\Exception Handling\Test\Filedrop\All_Exceptions\Exceptions_{B240CD10-240B-4CF9-8E58-C231036748F3}.xml 
 that xml contains following msg.

```
<Application>MOMIntegration</Application> 
  <Description>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Description> 
  <ErrorType>NullReferenceException</ErrorType> 
  <FailureCategory>Routing Failure</FailureCategory> 
  <FaultCode>2111</FaultCode> 
  <FaultDescription>Exception while attempting to work with Itinerary Step</FaultDescription> 
  <FaultSeverity>4</FaultSeverity> 
  <Scope>Construct Routing and Resolutoin Fault Message</Scope> 
  <ServiceInstanceID>3f5e22bc-2402-4f91-8996-22dcec3d4691</ServiceInstanceID> 
  <ServiceName>RGICLMOMIntegrationv2.MOMProcessor</ServiceName> 
  <FaultGenerator>Orchestration</FaultGenerator> 
  <MachineName>WIN-D3LS3QFCT5S</MachineName> 
  <DateTime>2012-10-22T06:00:52.209Z</DateTime> 
  <ControlBit>1</ControlBit> 
  <MessageID>b240cd10-240b-4cf9-8e58-c231036748f3</MessageID> 
  <ActivityIdentity /> 
  <NACK>false</NACK> 
  </Header>
- <ExceptionObject>
  <Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message> 
  <Type>System.NullReferenceException</Type> 
  <Source>RGICLMOMIntegrationv2</Source> 
  <TargetSite>Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.StopConditions segment2(Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.StopConditions)</TargetSite> 
  <StackTrace>at RGICLMOMIntegrationv2.MOMProcessor.segment2(StopConditions stopOn) at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)</StackTrace> 
  <InnerExceptionMessage /> 
  </ExceptionObject>
```

please let me know where I am going wrong. thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks like a variable is not instantiated in your orchestration. Check your variables and messages.